# How to create a union type of string literals with dynamic variables in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, union

I have an array of paths in my TypeScript backend package, which looks like this:

`const paths = ['create/{id}', 'delete/{ticketId}', 'get-all']`.

Now, I want to create a union type of string literals out of this array, where the dynamic variables in the paths are converted to a string type.

For instance, I want the final result to be something like this:

```
type BackEndPaths = keyof typeof paths // type BackEndPaths = "create/${string}" | "delete/${string}" | "get-all"
```

How can I achieve this in TypeScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a type to transform the string:

```
type TransformPath<S extends string> = S extends `${infer Path}{${string}}${infer Rest}` ? `${Path}${string}${TransformPath<Rest>}` : S;
```

then use:

```
type BackEndPaths = TransformPath<typeof paths[number]>;
```

However, it only works if you use `as const`:

```
const paths = ['create/{id}', 'delete/{ticketId}', 'get-all'] as const;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBADgQygCwjAvDA2gcmAJwFMlCB6AbwEsATAXxwBoYdrCAbQqM8qS4Aa04BJOo2YBzTgFoEbNmJyEAboTAUAtiCK0KodXDZ8SopjgBmIEKQBGCfBVsAvHQEcArgA8K7z-QC6MAhooJBQANwAsABQ0VAAnnCEMAAq+AiQFvjqAApIyAA8AMowhB5cYNRo0PiUYOIAfBgwxaXllTAABgAkVGBmhPgwuSi05D3VteK0tD21-YMASoTQtB0wAPydPcPIM+QTdXup6RCZOXn5S9D1qzAAXM2RMVHxiTAAQggCAKIVO2iYY4ZLTnFD5V6EEBmeB5CBYMBudTWAZ+ephIA)